# How to dualboot Win7 and Chrome-OS on Netbook

Tags: dual-boot, boot-loader, chrome, bootable, chrome-os

I have tested Google Chrome OS (aka Chromium OS) using a USB pen drive, or more precisely [Chrome OS Lime by Hexxeh](http://chromeos.hexxeh.net/lime.php).

Since I like it I would like to install it along side of my pre-installed Windows 7, however, I can not see any installation entry within the system..!

My *guess* is that one could do this by simply

1. Fix a partition
2. Make the partition it boot-able somehow
3. Copy the content of the USB-stick to the partition.
4. Add the partition to the boot loader using e.g. EasyBCD.exe.

Answer (score 1):

If you boot up Chrome OS from a pen drive, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to access the terminal. If you are using the Flow build, enter `/usr/sbin/chromeos-install` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Otherwise, just enter `install` and press Enter. You will be prompted for the root password; it is `facepunch`. Follow the prompts.

Note: The above method will erase everything on the hard disk to which you install Chrome OS, which isn't what you want.

As far as I know, the Chrome OS disk image provided by Hexxeh is comprised of two partitions, so copying the contents of the disk image to an empty partition won't work. I'm working on triple-booting Windows 8, Ubuntu, and Chrome OS; you can take a look at my question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56921/14410).

Of course, in my case, I already have a Linux system. In your case, you will have to install the GRUB2 boot-loader on top of Windows 7.